# Line spacing in overleaf changes the position of tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I am using overleaf to write an academic paper. When I insert the `linespacing` command at the very beginning, it pushes all the tables I have fitted with paragraphs to the very end of the document. It also increases the line spacing within these tables which I do not want. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry} %Command that creates the issue
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document} 
\section*{Introduction}
This is the text in first paragraph. This is the text in first paragraph. This is the text in first paragraph. 

\begin{table}[h]
   \small 
   \centering
   \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
   \label{tab:my-table}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
         \toprule
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ \midrule
          &  (1975-77) &  &  (1975-77) & \\
          &  &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  \\
         .
         .
         .
      \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show an image as well?

Comment: With your document example is not possible to reproduce your problem. Where can be find the package `dirtytalk`? Replace float positioning `[h]` to `[ht]`, this may solve your problem.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: Hi, I added the [ht] functionality to the tables and it didn't fix the issue. So the tables get pushed down to the very end of the document only when I add the line spacing command \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}.

If I take it out, the tables are exactly where I had placed them within the document. Is there anyway to attach the table to the corresponding paragraph?

Also, I am not sure how to attach an image since this is a fairly long document. And since this is in overleaf, I will be adding the overleaf tag. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zarko I traced the `dirtytalk`package to CTAN, although it is apparently not distributed at least through MikTeX (not sure about TeXlive). [https://ctan.org/pkg/dirtytalk] It appears to be a less well implemented version of `csquotes`, so I doubt it has anything to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: `[h]` and `[ht]` are not good: use `[htp]`.

Comment: @MarkusG., thank you for the info. From packane name I assume, that it is not relevant to OP problems. It seems, that table is so big, that it occupy almost entire page, so `ht` is not sufficient and need to be used `[htp]` (see egreg comment) or even `longtable` (without `table` float). However, for this are more information is needed (an MWE, which reproduce OP problem).